# gobject-introspection-1.48.0 fails to build

Tags: makefile, gtk3, gobject-introspection

Hello I was trying to build the latest GTK+ 3.0 on Debian Jessie.

After installing the required packages (lots of) I have to build gobject-introspection-1.48.0, but `make` command fails. `./config` ran without errors.

I looked for this issue and just found compile logs without solution.

This is the output:

http://pastebin.com/Tvpfc6wM

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Looks like you may be using a version of GLib that doesn't match what gobject-introspection expects. Try 2.48 or later.

Comment: I downloaded the latest sources available

Comment: Did you compile and install that latest version of GLib into the same prefix as you used to build gobject-introspection, first?

Depending on what you’re using it for, you might find building GTK+ 3 easier with [JHBuild](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildGnome).